# Finding Average V Value of HSV Matrix Column Within Bounded Area

Tags: android, opencv

I'm new to using OpenCV with Android Studio and was wondering how to go about the following problem.
I currently have an Image in BMP format which I have converted to an HSV matrix and separated the channels. I want to create a bounding rectangle at a specific location and calculate the average V value for each column within that area.
How can I go about achieving this?